# Canon 600D says "Card write error"

Tags: canon, sdcard

My Canon 600D was showing "Card write error".

I took out my SD card and noticed that the write-protect lock was broken, so I bought a new one.

I am still getting the same error on the new card although it is not locked.  The new card works fine in a computer.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error?  If it just says "write error" that may not be related to the write-protect lock on the card.

Comment: Did you try the cards in a computer or any other camera?

Comment: Search "card error" on this site...

Comment: The card works fine with a computer. It gives the same error with a new card as well :(

Comment: Agree with James. Take your Canon 600D to nearest showroom. ****Maybe the lock of old card is stuck in the slot.****

Comment: Yea will try to take it to a local repairer. Looks like there is an issue with the card slot :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your 600D has failed and needs servicing or the new card you have purchased is not compatible with your camera.

I would recommend that you consult Canon's service department or, if cost is an issue, a local repairer.  Most camera shops will be offer a service or be able to put you in touch with someone.

Comment: I will take it to a local repairer, thnx guys!

Comment: Took the camera to a local repair shop...all fixed now. Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: "Either your 600D has failed and needs servicing or the new card you have purchased is not compatible with your camera." - quite possible though, OP might have bought SDXC.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, I hit the same issue a long time back; totally messed up my 600D. I even bought new SD cards and tried, but nothing worked. I finally understood that it had a problem with the SD card slot that holds the SD card. Go to a service center and change the card slot, it costs approximately 2000 INR (30$).