# About Card's write protect switch in Canon EOS 70D

Tags: sdcard

In my Canon EOS 70D camera, when I insert the SD memory card, the screen shows Card's write protect switch is set to lock. This is in spite of having pushed the card's lock switch up.. The card works in another canon camera. What else should I do?

Comment: Are you able to try a different memory card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canon 600D says "Card write error"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70389/canon-600d-says-card-write-error)

Comment: We have tried another card in it to no avail; the cards work in other canon cameras

Comment: The switch is nothing more than a piece of plastic, not being read out by the SD card. The cardreader itself checks the position of the slider and  should refuse to write data if necessary. If this doesn't work, the camera refuses to write any card.

Comment: Possibly some dirt in the card slot. Did you try to blow some air in there?